# How to list all circuits of an oriented matroid and all circuits of its contraction of a vertex by hand?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry, matroids

For example, the oriented matroid CUBE has $40$ signed circuits. Its contraction to the vertex $8$ has $34$ signed circuits.

[image]

What is a smart way to list out all the circuits without missing out or double-counting any?

Answer (score 2):

Taking *by hand* a little loosely, one could use a computer.

The software [TOPCOM](http://www.rambau.wm.uni-bayreuth.de/TOPCOM/) can compute the signed circuits of a point configuration. Both [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) and [Macaulay2](https://github.com/Macaulay2/M2) have packages for working with matroids (see [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/matroids/index.html) and [here](https://github.com/jchen419/Matroids-M2), respectively). Either could compute all of the circuits of the underlying unoriented matroid, leaving you the work of signing them.

Computing the circuits without a computer necessitates good bookkeeping. Writing down the circuits lexicographically can be helpful when checking that nothing was missed.

Comment: Thanks. Some of the exercises I'm doing require computing the circuits by hand. I suppose that their goal is just to make sure people understand the mechanism. In the future the software you've recommended would definitely help.

Comment: If possible, could you please look at this question? Thanks. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658469/relationship-between-affine-dependence-and-linear-dependence-in-oriented-matroid

Comment: The TOPCOM link is broken - new location seems to be this one: https://www.wm.uni-bayreuth.de/de/team/rambau_joerg/TOPCOM/index.html