# Relationship between Affine Dependence and Linear Dependence in Oriented Matroids?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry, matroids

I'm reading "Lectures on Polytopes" by Gunter Ziegler.

The author first introduces the components of oriented matroids in affine case,

[image]

then making a transition to linear case, with the condition "1z = 0" embedded into the matrix V.

[image]
[image]
[image]

In the subsequent discussion, the author seems to use only the linear notions, such as in this one:

[image]

However, this is just my guess. I'm not sure if it is the case. Is it correct to assume that the matrix V in Definition 6.5. has only 1's in its first row? If not, please explain why the condition "1z = 0" is no longer necessary. All the theory the author's built up up to this point have this condition.

Comment: A general oriented matroid can be defined from any vector configuration, not just one that comes from an affine configuration. While oriented matroids from affine configurations are relevant for polytopes, I imagine Ziegler is writing about general vector configurations because there is a general theory of oriented matroids, and Ziegler wishes to be consistent with that larger body of work.